# Code to check for the optimality of a minimal prefix free code

Tags: python

As a follow-up to my previous [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/computation-of-prefix-free-codes-with-many-repeated-weight-values-in-reduced-spa) about prefix free code, I learned about the module unittest and wrote the following set of functions, to be used in order to semi-automatically check the optimality of the output of any new algorithm to compute prefix free code.

The code works but I would like it to be as elegant (and compact) as possible in order to potentially include it in a research article, in a more formal and reproducible maneer than the traditional "algorithm". I am proud of how it looks, but I do expect you to still criticize it!!!

```
import unittest, doctest, math

def codeIsPrefixFreeCodeMinimal(L,W):
    """Checks if the prefix free code described by an array $L$ of
    pairs $(codeLenght_i,nbWeights_i)$ is minimal for weights $W$, by
    1) checking if the code respects Kraft's inequality and 
    2) comparing the lenght of a code encoded with $L$ with the
    entropy of $W$.
    """
    assert respectsKraftInequality(L)
    return compressedTextLenght(L,W) <= NTimesEntropy(W)+len(W)



def respectsKraftInequality(L):
    """Checks if the given array $L$ of pairs $(codeLenght_i,nbWeights_i)$ 
    corresponds to a prefix free code by checking Kraft's inequality, i.e.
    $\sum_i nbWeights_i 2^{-codelenght_i} \leq 1$.
    """ 
    return KraftSum(L) <= 1 ;
def KraftSum(L):
    """Computes the Kraft sum of the prefix free code described by an
    array $L$ of pairs $(codeLenght_i,nbWeights_i)$ i.e.  
    $\sum_i nbWeights_i 2^{-codelenght_i}$.
    """
    if len(L)==0: 
        return 0
    terms = map( lambda x: x[1] * math.pow(2,-x[0]), L)
    return sum(terms)
class TestKraftSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_empty(self):
        """Empty input."""
        self.assertEqual(KraftSum([]),0)
    def test_singleton(self):
        """Singleton with one single symbol."""
        self.assertEqual(KraftSum([(0,1)]),1)
    def test_simpleCode(self):
        """Simple Code with code lenghts [1,2,2]."""
        self.assertEqual(KraftSum([(1,1),(2,2)]),1)
    def test_fourEqual(self):
        """Four equal weights"""
        self.assertEqual(KraftSum([(2,4)]),1)
    def test_HuffmanExample(self):
        """Example from Huffman's article"""
        self.assertEqual(KraftSum([(5,6),(4,3),(3,3),(2,1)]),1)
    def test_MoffatTurpinExample(self):
        """Example from Moffat and Turpin's article"""
        self.assertEqual(KraftSum([(5,4),(4,4),(3,3),(2,1)]),1)


def NTimesEntropy(W):
    """Returns N times the entropy, rounded to the next integer, as computed by
       $\lceil \sum_{i=1}^N W[i]/\sum(W) \log (sum(W) / W[i]) \rceil$.
       """
    if len(W)==0: 
        return 0
    assert min(W)>0
    sumWeights = sum(W)    
    terms = map( lambda x: x * math.log(x,2), W )
    return math.ceil(sumWeights * math.log(sumWeights,2) - sum(terms)) 
class TestNTimesEntropy(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_empty(self):
        """Empty input"""
        self.assertEqual(NTimesEntropy([]),0)
    def test_singleton(self):
        """Singleton"""
        self.assertEqual(NTimesEntropy([1]),0)
    def test_pair(self):
        """Pair"""
        self.assertEqual(NTimesEntropy([1,1]),2)
    def test_fourEqual(self):
        """Four equal weights"""
        self.assertEqual(NTimesEntropy([1,1,1,1]),8)
    def test_HuffmanExample(self):
        """Example from Huffman's article"""
        self.assertEqual(NTimesEntropy([1,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,10,10,10,18,20]),336)
    def test_MoffatTurpinExample(self):
        """Example from Moffat and Turpin's article"""
        self.assertEqual(NTimesEntropy([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,6]),84)

def compressedTextLength(L,W):
    """Computes the lengths of a text which frequencies are given by
    an array $W$, when it is compressed by a prefix free code
    described by an array $L$ of pairs $(codeLenght_i,nbWeights_i)$.
    """
    compressedTextLength = 0
    Ls = sorted(L, reverse=True)
    Ws = sorted(W)
    for (l,n) in Ls:
        compressedTextLength += l*sum(Ws[0:n])
        Ws = Ws[n:]
    return compressedTextLength
class TestcompressedTextLength(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_empty(self):
        """Empty input"""
        self.assertEqual(compressedTextLength([],[]),0)
    def test_pair(self):
        """Pair of symbols, arbitrary text"""
        self.assertEqual(compressedTextLength([(1,2)],[1,1]),2)
    def test_fourEqual(self):
        """Four equal weights"""
        self.assertEqual(compressedTextLength([(2,4)],[1,1,1,1]),8)
    def test_HuffmanExample(self):
        """Example from Huffman's article (compares with value compared by hand)"""
        self.assertEqual(compressedTextLength([(5,6),(4,3),(3,3),(2,1)],[1,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,10,10,10,18,20]),342)
    def test_MoffatTurpinExample(self):
        """Example from Moffat and Turpin's article (compares with entropy value)"""
        self.assertEqual(compressedTextLength([(5,4),(4,4),(3,3),(2,1)],[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,6]),84)


def main():
    unittest.main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Most Python I read these days prefers list comprehensions over `map` or `filter`. For example, I'd change

```
terms = map( lambda x: x[1] * math.pow(2,-x[0]), L)
return sum(terms)
```

to

```
return sum(x[1] * math.pow(2, -x[0]) for x in L)
```

---

You consistently misspell "length" as "lenght".

---

Your formatting is odd. Sometimes you have 3 blank lines between functions, sometimes 0. Likewise, sometimes you write `foo <= bar` and sometimes `foo=bar+baz`. Sometimes your functions begin with a lowercase letter (`compressedTextLength`, `respectsKraftInequality`) and sometimes with an uppercase (`KraftSum`). Look over [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for formatting recommendations.

---

In `compressedTextLength`, you can rewrite

```
for (l,n) in Ls:
    compressedTextLength += l*sum(Ws[0:n])
    Ws = Ws[n:]
```

as

```
for i, (l, n) in enumerate(Ls):
    compressedTextLength += l * sum(Ws[i:i+n])
```

---

You call `doctest.testmod()` but it doesn't look like you have any doctests.

---

As a generalized note, I would find it difficult to learn anything about this algorithm from reading your code. I also have no idea how to use this module. I would add a docstring to the beginning of the module telling the reader about the functions they should care about, and in each function's docstring I would document what the arguments should be and what the return values are (arrays of ints? floating point numbers? etc).

It looks like this may be a test harness for code that actually computes minimal prefix free codes. If that's a case, document it in the module's docstring.